# How should I properly store and retrieve IPs?

Tags: mysql-5.5

I have table **`Users`** with one column **`user`** of type **`VARCHAR(15)`**. I can insert a period into it:

```
INSERT INTO `LJ`.`Users` (`user`) VALUES ('.')
```

Now I want to search for this period:

```
SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `user` LIKE '.'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `user` = '.'
```

In both cases, the existing entry is not found:

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0001 sec)

The same problem with the comma.

Actually, my intention is to store IP addresses like 125.50.75.80, but I've boiled the problem down to inability to search for a punctuation sign. I tried '\.' also to no avail.

And this is a problem with literals; what to do with variables, containing strings with periods?

UPDATE: I've tested in a database created in the command line with table:

```
CREATE TABLE LJ.Users ( user VARCHAR(15) );
```

and everything works OK. I suspect something is wrong in my database created with phpMyAdmin:

[image: table]

Comment: Dear @Prix, it is extremely helpful, thank you very much! It does work now flawlessly and efficiently! I presume you are involved with SQL Fiddle? I am going to make a donation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The current issue with your `VARCHAR` column is the collate type you're using `armscii8_general_ci` which converts some of the stored characters such as comma and dot.**

[**See example here.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a3ece/2)

Perhaps you meant to use `utf8_general_ci` which would yield your desired results:

[**See example here.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37f11/1)

---

Do not use `VARCHAR` to store IPv4, use `INT unsigned` and then you can use [`INET_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and [`INET_NTOA()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) functions to return/insert/compare the IPv4.

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    user_ip INT unsigned
);
```

Then to insert an IPv4 you would use:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_ip) VALUES (INET_ATON('125.50.75.80'));
```

Then you could read it like this:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(user_ip) FROM users WHERE user_ip = INET_ATON('125.50.75.80')
```

[**Live DEMO.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/affad/2/1)

Comment: Attention: IPv6 addresses are not working :-) It does "null"! Should be mentioned in this time and for "new" technologies.

Comment: @DennisZiolkowski As the OP is storing IPv4 and not IPv6 it was needless to say, judging at his column size, regardless I've updated it to reflect its for IPv4