# Query to get data from 3 tables using a single table contains only foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have 4 tables below cluster, production, testcases, cluster_production_testcases

```
Cluster table
|id_cluster(PK)|cluster_name|Cluster_ipaddress|
|1             |a1          |10.x1.sss.xxx|
|2             |a1          |10.x2.sss.xxx|
|3             |a2          |10.x3.sss.xxx|

Production table
|ip_production(PK) | production_name|
|1                 |Test1 |
|2                 |Test2 |


TestCases table
|id_testcases(PK)|testcase_name|ip_production(FK)|
|1               |Hello1       |1 |
|2               |Hello2       |1 |
|3               |Hello2       |2 |

Cluster_Production_Testcases
|id_cpt(PK) | id_cluster(FK) | id_production(FK)  |
|1          | 1              | 1  |
|2          | 2              | 1  |
|3          | 1              | 2  |
|4          | 2              | 2  |
```

How to get `cluster_name`, `cluster_ipaddress`, `production_name` and `testcase_name` which all are links together using primary and foreign key using `cluster_production_testcases` table.

Comment: [You might want to read this in regards how you're storing your IPs.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266994/how-should-i-properly-store-and-retrieve-ips/26267518#26267518)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using implicit (you could use ANSI as well) join:

```
SELECT c.cluster_name, c.cluster_ipaddress, p.production_name, t.testcase_name
FROM  Cluster c, Production p, Testcases t, Cluster_production_Testcases cpt
WHERE cpt.id_cluster = c.id_cluster
AND   cpt.id_production = p.ip_production
AND   p.ip_production = t.ip_production
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Its work. Also, could you please help me to make the same query with JOIN if possible.

Comment: It is join which is of type implicit.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. With the help of that I have completed the database structure and with dummy data I am able to get the final result table successfully. Now I want to insert the value in the tables using the query and other table which are linked should get field automatically. Please help me in this.

Comment: @Alex Glad it helped. You would need to raise a new request further so that forum members can help you. Dont forget to show what you did and why it's not helping you to achieve target.

Comment: Yes Almas, I have created a new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593168/insert-and-update-query-for-the-table-links-together-with-keys with the query. It would be great if you can help.